# GNU Make: no output when using `define var =`

Tags: variables, makefile

Snippet 1:

```
define HELP_TEXT
This is the help text.
endef

.PHONY: help
help:
      @echo $(HELP_TEXT)
```

Test:

```
$ make help
This is the help text.
$
```

Snippet 2:

```
define HELP_TEXT =
This is the help text.
endef

.PHONY: help
help:
      @echo $(HELP_TEXT)
```

Test:

```
$ make help

$
```

What is going on here? According to the documentation there should be no difference in behaviour between both syntaxes.

NOTE: My GNU Make version is 3.81.

Comment: I don't have `make` 3.81 to hand but... the `makefile` shown in Snippet 2 works fine with `GNU Make 4.2.1`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The NEWS file for version 3.82 (28 Jul 2010) mentions this:

> - The `define` make directive now allows a variable assignment operator after the variable name, to allow for simple, conditional, or appending multi-line variable assignment.

So it's simply a feature not present in GNU make 3.81.  In fact, in earlier make versions, the variable is called `HELP_TEXT =`, as can be seen if you try this:

```
define HELP_TEXT =
This is the help text.
endef

.PHONY: help
help:
    @echo $(HELP_TEXT =)
```

Comment: Seriously? Just for one minor version? That is called luck haha. What I wanted to do is to use `define :=` to use inmediate assignment instead of deferred; so I have to rely on deferred assignment then.

Comment: @Peregring-lk may  ask which evil system you are on that doesn't allow you to use a more modern version of GNUmake? It shouldn't be too much of a hassle to build the latest version, given ....er, well your system isn't too evil.

Comment: @Vroomfondel Of course I can add the GNU make repositories, but I'm writting a makefile library for different production and developing servers and I prefer to rely on current supported versions.

Comment: @Peregring-lk in case you look for some general programming language features, take a look at [gmtt](https://github.com/markpiffer/gmtt).